# Embed variable using sys.stdout.write in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I can embed variables using the print statement in python in this way

```
i=10
print "Value is %s" % (i)
```

Output

> ```
> Value is 10
> ```

but doing this

```
i=10
sys.stdout.write ("Value is %s") % (i)
```

gives me the following error

> ```
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'NoneType' and 'int'
> ```

Can I embed variables using sys.stdout.write instead of print?

Comment: Not surprising that you get an error, since the syntax is so wrong.

Comment: @S.Lott The question is pretty much useless now. I cannot delete it since it has answers.

Comment: Not utterly useless -- there's a possibility that other people may have the same syntax question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You got the parentheses wrong.  Should be

```
i=10
sys.stdout.write("Value is %s" % i)
```

The `%` operator takes a string and a tuple (or a single object) as arguments.  You tried to apply the operator to the return value of `sys.stdout.write()`, which is None.  You need to apply it to the string before it is passed to `sys.stdout.write()`.